# What is the URL to start a Google Hangout Video Chat?

Tags: google-hangouts

You can generate a button using JavaScript, as detailed here: https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/button.

But I'm looking for a way to get a direct URL to start a video chat. I know it's possible; Slack somehow does it with their Hangouts integration. But I'm stumped as to how they do it.